# How can i insert exception in data base getting from execute command on remote server using SSH

Tags: java, mysql, exception, ssh

How can i insert this exception getting from execute command on remote server in data base

```
bash: -c: line 0: Erreur de syntaxe près du symbole inattendu « ) »
bash: -c: line 0: `df -)h'
```

i'm connecting on remote server and i'm executing multiple commands and i'm getting the output and i'm saving it in my data base.Now i want to save exception on my data base when command it's not executing or any other exception how can i do that? can i use **((channelExc)channel).setErrStream(System.err)** to get the exception and how can i use it?

Comment: get the errorstream of your shell and save it in database.